# display buttons in outer array object and check box with inner array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, dropdown

i am trying to display two buttons in outer nested array object in select dropdown menu and checkbox in inner nested array object and i have mentioned below the nested array below dropwdown is showing but buttons are not

```
const options = [
             {
              name: "Group 1",
              options: [
               {
                value: "Option 1",
                label: "Option 1",
               },
               {
               value: "Option 2",
               label: "Option 2",
               },
              {
               value: "Option 3",
               label: "Option 3",
              },
              ],
             },
            {
            name: "Group 2",
            options: [
            {
             value: "Option 4",
             label: "Option 4",
             },
             {
              value: "Option 5",
              label: "Option 5",
              },
              {
              value: "Option 6",
              label: "Option 6",
             },
            ],
           },
          ];
```

here i have created a function to display dropdown item

```
 const optionsList = options.map((group) => {
      <div>
      <button>SELECT All</button>
      <button>Clear</button>
     </div>
     return (
      <optgroup label={group.name}>
      {group.options.map((option) => (
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
        {option.label}
        </option>
       ))}
      </optgroup>
     );
   });

      return (

      <select onChange={handleChange} value={selectedOption}>
        {optionsList}
       </select>
      </div> 

       );
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach using `map` won't work, because you need all the options but your outer option group is less than all the options (6 total options but 2 option groups).

Here is my solution, by using an empty array for `option`s, you can add all the nested options in a single array and then it can be used in your returned JSX.

```js
const allOptions = [];

options.forEach((optionGroup) => {
  optionGroup.options.forEach((option) => {
    return allOptions.push(
      <option key={option.value}>{`${optionGroup.name}:${option.label}`}</option>
    );
  });
});
  
return (
  <div>
    <select value="placeholder" onChange={() => "placeholder"}>
      {allOptions}
    </select>
  </div>
);
```